# JPA Many To One persistence issue at fetching data

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-one

I have two table as `hotel` and `hotal_room_type`. And there is Many To One mapping from `hotal_room_type` to `hotel`. Means Primary key of `hotel` is foreign key in `hotal_room_type`.

Now I am fetching `hotal_room_type` data usfing following code

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from "
            + HotelsRoomType.class.getName() + " where event.id = "
            + eventId);
List<HotelsRoomType> list = query.getResultList();
```

When I get two records of HotelRoomType having same Hotel then I got Hotel only for first HotelRoomType. For other HotelRoomTypes It gives Hotel object but having 0 in `hotelId` variable , means I am unable to receive Hotel object again.

I need to get complete Hotel entity for all HotelRoomTypes. How to make this possible?

Comment: What is event.id? Please post your mapping classes.......

Comment: Event is an another mapping entity in HotelsRoomType table. Main problem is in fetching Hotel entity.

Comment: use join to get all datas

Comment: join on which column or property? I have used @JoinColumn annotation in Hotel property

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my answer. I need to add `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` in the mapping of the `Hotel` entity. Like :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "hot_room_frn_hot_id", nullable = false)
public Hotel getHotel() {
    return this.hotel;
}
```